# Gdalwarp UTM reprojection causes image distortions

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, sentinel-2

I'm trying to re-project Sentinel-2 images to a common UTM zone in order to create a mosaic.

For this I'm using gdalwarp with the following syntax:

```
C:/OSGeo4W64/OSGeo4W.bat; gdalwarp -t_srs \"+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0\" -tr 10 10 img1_UTM35s.tif img2_UTM36s_reproj.tif
```

While the execution works fine, the results show some funny distortions. It seems like groups of pixels inside the image rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise which leads to a small shift as seen in this image:

[image: Image distortion]

The right side shows the same part of the original image as reprojected to UTM36S. Inside the red circles you can see (albeit barely) the shift of the pixels resulting in apparent edges.

Did anyone experience this already?

Comment: Which resampling method did you use? The default is nearest neighbour.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I can't believe I didn't think about that! Of course, it was set to default NN. Using bilinear the results are much better. Thank you!